# Validar existencia de un email con C#

Tags: c#

Tengo esta función en la cual pretendo validar la existencia de un email. Pero me marca un error en la creación de la instancia de la  función:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  bool bandera = checkDNS("soyplato3@gmail.com", "MX");
}

public bool checkDNS(string host, string recType) {
  bool result = false;
  try {
    using(Process proc = new Process()) {
      proc.StartInfo.FileName = "nslookup";
      proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-type={0} {1}", recType, host);
      proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
      proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
      proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      proc.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => {
        if ((e.Data != null) && (!result))
          result = e.Data.StartsWith(host);
      };
      proc.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => {
        if (e.Data != null) {
          //read error output here, not sure what for?
        }
      };
      proc.Start();
      proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
      proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
      proc.WaitForExit(30000); //timeout after 30 seconds.
    }
  } catch {
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
}
```

El error se lanza aquí:

```
bool bandera = checkDNS("soyplato3@gmail.com","MX");
```

Con la excepción:

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property

Comment: Que error? Donde exactamente?

Comment: using (Process proc = new Process())

Comment: Pero que excepción de da exactamente?

Comment: Ya actualicé la pregunta donde indico el error

Comment: Creo que tiene que ver con que estas llamando desde una funcion estatica a una que no lo es. Prueba con public static bool checkDNS(string host, string recType)

Comment: Exacto. Como dice @Lithorell el problema es que el método `checkDNS` no es estático. De todas maneras...esto no es asp.net?

Comment: Podes confirmar que esto es ASP.net?? hay un metodo main, y llamadas a procesos.. no parece ASP.net

Comment: Una disculpa, me confundí, es una console Aplication, La costumbre de ASP.NET me confundí, ya corregí también la pregunta

Comment: Como comentario, con `nslookup` no vas a conseguir saber si un email es válido o no. En todo caso, podrás comprobar si el servidor existe...

Comment: chispas, me imaginé que eso pasaría, es que la idea es validar el email, pero no encuentro nada T.T, de hecho esto fue algo que encontré en la web

Comment: No es posible validar una cuenta de correo. Existe un comando verify conectandote al servidor de correo para ver si existe, pero a cuenta de los spammers, actualmente yo diría que todos los servidores o lo bloquean o directamente mienten

Comment: Y esta función verify se puede utilizar en c#?. porque veo las páginas como http://verify-email.org/ que hacen lo que yo quiero hacer

Comment: La **única** forma de validar un email correctamente es enviando un mail, esperando alguna acción del destinatario para confirmarlo.

Comment: Te vuelvo a decir lo mismo. **No existe** ningun metodo que funcione al 100% para comprobar si una cuenta de email existe realmente

Comment: @Mariano ya usé el SMTP Client, pero cuando el correo no existe, no logro capturar ese error en tiempo real, sino que el SMTP cliente envia el correo y hasta que no puedo envia un correo con el que envié el otro correo notificando el error. Yo necesito que me diga al instante que existe o no el correo

Comment: @Pikoh pero me podría funcionar, cómo puedo investigar lo que me dijiste?

Comment: El comando VRFY **ya no funciona** en ningun servidor de correo moderno para evitar el spam.

Comment: fuera del vrfy, ya no hay otra opción, verdad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo checkDNS debe ser estatico.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool bandera = checkDNS("soyplato3@gmail.com","MX");
}



public static bool checkDNS(string host, string recType) // Aqui esta el cambio
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "nslookup";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-type={0} {1}", recType, host);
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if ((e.Data != null) && (!result))
                    result = e.Data.StartsWith(host);
            };
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    //read error output here, not sure what for?
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.WaitForExit(30000); //timeout after 30 seconds.
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: gracia, ya corregí el problema, disculpa, sabes para que es, la clase "process"

Comment: No la he usado nunca pero viendo la documentación es para trabajar con procesos y poder arrancarlos y pararlos https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Es que quiero validar un correo, pero no se si eso me sirva

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx.. usar google es mucho mas facil.. y no, eso no sirve para validar un correo...@ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez

Comment: Conocer de alguna función para validar un correo?

Comment: ¿validar que el correo este bien escrito o que exista?